# Change prices according to quantity and location

Tags: wordpress

I need to change the prices of various articles in WordPress, according to the quantity that is requested, and in the same way that the prices are different depending on where you are buying. For example, buying 1 apple in Mexico costs 5 dlls and buying 5 costs 20 dlls. But buying 1 apple in the US costs 8 dlls and buying 5 costs 36 dlls. Any plug-in or way to do it?

Comment: Woocommerce with combination with this plugin https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing-discounts/7119279 which will give you tones of options such as buy 4 get 5th at 50% with additional rules like shipping address , payment methods, is it new customer or returned etc. They have demo where you can test all your needed rules before purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment above, I solved this with two WP plugins, the first one is [Country Based Restrictions](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-country-base-restrictions/) which allowed me to create products and decide in which countries they can be seen. The second is [Dynamic Pricing With Discount](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/aco-woo-dynamic-pricing/) which you can create different prices depending on the number of products